# Incomplete Java fileoutputstream with textfiles

Tags: java, encryption, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I am coding a little tool to encrypt and decrypt files. The encrypted files will be added to a zip-archive. The following code is working so far. I can encrypt any files but textfiles. If I choose a textfile it is written incomplete. If there is the following text:
"one two three test check check test" it gets cut like "one two three test che".

There is no exception thrown just a few bytes are missing. Any other files (pdf, mp3, mp4, exe and so forth) are written completely.

```
package encryptme.crypto;

import encryptme.fileoperations.FileIn;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class Encrypt {

    private String algorithm;
    private int keylength;
    private Key key;
    private KeyPair keypair;
    private File[] source;
    private String destination;

    public Encrypt(String a, int kl, Key k, File[] s, String dest) {
        this.algorithm = a;
        this.keylength = kl;
        this.key = k;
        this.source = s;
        this.destination = dest;
        this.output = o;
    }

    public void encOut() {
        CipherOutputStream cout = null;
        ZipOutputStream zout = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(this.destination);
            System.out.println(this.destination);
            zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(this.algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.key);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.source.length; i++) {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.source[i].getAbsolutePath());
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(this.source[i].getName());                 
                zout.putNextEntry(ze);
                cout = new CipherOutputStream(zout, cipher);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                long bytesRead = 0;
                for (bytesRead = 0; (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                    cout.write(buffer, 0, (int) bytesRead);
                }
                zout.closeEntry();
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cout != null) {
                    cout.close();
                }
                if (zout != null) {
                    zout.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Encrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The files to be encrypted are chosen with a jFileChooser and added to an array which gets passed in to the class above as parameter. I thought about using a PrintWriter for those textfiles identifying them by their ending e.g. 'textfile.txt' or 'textfile.odt'. But what shall I do if the file does not have an ending just like 'textfile'?

I'm pretty new to Java and coding in general so I hope there is just a bad mistake which causes the problem.

Comment: If you skip the cipher output stream and just use a regular stream does it work?

Comment: If i write directly to the ZipOutputStream it works.

Comment: Try flushing and then closing the CipherOutputStream?

Comment: Did you tried changing buffer size as byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; Does your bytesread count increases buffer size?

Comment: Flushing and closing does not take any effect. Increasing the buffer size does not work, too.

Comment: 'bytesRead' should be declared as 'int', not 'long'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `cout` before you call `zout.closeEntry` in order to flush out any remaining data that the cipher has buffered. Unfortunately, `cout.close()` will call `zout.close()`, which we definitely don't want because that will stop you writing any further entries.

I would use the [CloseShieldOutputStream from commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CloseShieldOutputStream.html):

```
cout = new CipherOutputStream(new CloseShieldOutputStream(zout), cipher);
```

This class is designed to stop the `close()` call from propagating to the underlying wrapped stream (in this case `zout`).

Comment: This is it! Works like a charm now. I tried closing the CipherOutputStream without the CloseShieldOutputStream before and like you said this caused the ZipOutputStream to close. I've been sitting on this for weeks... Thank you very much.

Comment: @Seppel this is why I wish more filtering stream types had a `finish()` method like GZIPOutputStream has, to separate the "finish what you're doing" from the "and close the underlying stream". But in the absence of that the close shield streams are a handy tool.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking, but do you want to sanitize the array of files your receive to your Encrypt class? One way indeed is to look at the file extension:

```
public class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter {

        private String[] imageExtentions = {"png", "jpg", "gif" };

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
                for(String ext : imageExtentions){
                        if(file.isFile()){
                                if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))
                                        return true;
                        }
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

The above example is a class which is supposed to handle image extensions, but its generic so it will work for any extention thats passed into the accept method. The key is to implment the FileFilter interface, then you can sanitize your files.

Edit:
ahh, you edited your question which makes it more clear about what you want, which is not what the answer I've given solves.

Comment: Sanitizing the array was one idea to solve the problem. But if the file does not have an extension I cannot use this. What I mean is a Textfile usually looks like 'file.txt'. If it is only 'file' without .txt your solution won't work.

Comment: @Seppel did you try and see if it excludes file extensions ending with ".txt", in any case, you can use a regex to solve your problem. Like in the accept method, write a regular expression that checks if the file doesn't end with ".txt"

Comment: The missing file extension was just a theoretical case. If the user removed the extension in order to "hide" it. I think I will write some FileFilters and use a StreamWriter for textfiles. Files which does not match will not be encrypted and the user will get an error message. The only thing I cannot figure out is why it works without the CipherOutputStream.